# How to delete a row from a JDBC recordset (XPages with relational extlib)

Tags: jdbc, xpages, xpages-extlib

I am using extlib relational from org.openntf.
Studied the example database, but nothing found about recordSet.deleteRow(rowindex).

Create & change works perfect. I also can delete rows via the simple Action "Delete seleted documents", but I would like to delete a specific row. Ie. an action "Delete" in an dialogBox.

> recordSet.deleteRow(rowindex) throws: Java method
>   'deleteRow(java.lang.Double)' on java class
>   'com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational.jdbc.model.JdbcRowSetAccessor' not
>   found

Any ideas?

Thanks
Ernst

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes reading the exception helps a lot :-)
My rowIndex was double not int .. with argument int, it works perfect.